# How to choose from jhipster uaa and jhipster keycloak?

Tags: jhipster

As I'm choosing the central user authentication module,  I found Jhipster provided uaa and keycloak/okta. In my opinion, keycloak may be more general as it is used by all kinds of applications and can easily integrate with other systems, but uaa seems to be well integrated with other jhipster modules. How can I choose from the two? Thanks!

Comment: I would also really like to hear some oppinions on this - what are peoples experience with this and what have they noted as pros and cons. I will perhaps attempt to supply an answer to this myself, as I am throwing myself at another JHipster project right now. Going to start out with Keycloak (have done that before, but just for some POC work) and see where it takes me.